# JAXB element showing the SuperClass name and the Class name as an attribute

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling, hierarchy

I'm trying to serialize in XML some objects using JAXB, and when I get to a field being an abstract Class pointer, I get this code serialized:

> ```
> <Message>
>     <MessageID>1</MessageID>
>     <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
>     **<Content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="product">**
>         <SKU>skuparent</SKU> ...
> ```

But what I would need is like:

> ```
> <Message>
>     <MessageID>1</MessageID>
>     <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
>     **<Product>**
>         <SKU>skuparent</SKU>
> ```

And I don't get to transform it using "@XMLTransient" tagging, that's the only proposition I got from the other posts

My code is this:

```
@XmlType(propOrder = { "MessageID", "operationType", "Content"})
public static class message{
    public int MessageID;
    private String OperationType;
    @XmlElement(name ="OperationType")
    public String getOperationType() {
        return OperationType;
    }

    public void setOperationType(String _operationType) {
        OperationType = operationType.valueOf(_operationType).toString();
    }

    public AmazonContent Content;
}
```

Where "AmazonContent" is an Abstract Class like that:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Product.class})
public abstract class AmazonContent {

}
```

and the subClass instance is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Product")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "SKU", "StandardProductID", "DescriptionData", "ProductData"})
public class Product extends AmazonContent {
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A detail Blaise Doughan missed possibly due to later updates of the Api, and I found here:

http://old.nabble.com/Re:-XmlElementRef-points-to-a-non-existent-class-p22366506.html

The XmlReference should be parametrized as follows

The abstract class is pointedhere:

```
public static class productData{
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(type = Shoes.class),
        @XmlElementRef(type = Clothing.class)
    })
    public AmazonProductData Product; //Abstract AmazonProductData
}
```

and these are the SubClasses:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Shoes")
public class Shoes extends AmazonProductData {
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Clothing")
public class Clothing extends AmazonProductData {
```

nothing else needed, nor *@XmlTransient*, nor *@XmlSeeAlso* or anything

hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

By default a JAXB implementation will leverage the `xsi:type` attribute as the descriminator node when representing inheritance:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

Using the element name as the inheritance indicator corresponds to the XML schema concept of substitution groups which can be mapped with the `@XmlElementRef` annotation.  The element name for the value will be what was specified on the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on the reference class.

```java
@XmlElementRef
public AmazonContent Content;
```

For more information:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Comment: Perfect Blaise! I was starting to freak out and I coded all the patching for further XPath looking for the attributes and swaping of the names. Shame on me.